# Requet to hasura with apollo client and NextAuth

Tags: next.js, jwt, apollo-client, next-auth, hasura

I'm trying send get data from Hasura with apollo client and the token of NextAuth but I cannot and I got the error message.

"Could not verify JWT: JWSError (CompactDecodeError Invalid number of parts: Expected 3 parts; got 5)"

I've checked some articles but I haven't found the solution yet.
Could you tell me how I can do to get data from Hasura?

Here are the codes.

#### [...nextauth].tsx

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { HasuraAdapter } from "@skillrecordings/next-auth-hasura-adapter";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID || "",
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET || "",
    }),
  ],
  adapter: HasuraAdapter({
    endpoint: process.env.HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT || "",
    adminSecret: process.env.HASURA_ADMIN_SECRET || "",
  }),
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return {
        ...token,
        "https://hasura.io/jwt/claims": {
          "x-hasura-allowed-roles": ["user"],
          "x-hasura-default-role": "user",
          "x-hasura-user-id": token.sub,
        },
      };
      // return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.user.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      return session;
    },
  },
});
```

#### token.tsx

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

const secret = "<Same as HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET>";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const token = await getToken({ req, secret, raw: true });

  res.json({ token });
}
```

#### apollo-client.tsx

```
import {
  createHttpLink,
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloProvider,
  HttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
} from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/link-context";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { FC, ReactNode } from "react";

export const AuthApolloProvider: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: "https://fgn-library.hasura.app/v1/graphql",
  });

  const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
    const { token } = await fetch("/api/auth/token").then((res) => res.json());
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };
  });

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });

  return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>;
};
```

#### HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET

{
"key": "<Same as Token.tsx>",
"type": "HS256"
}

Comment: You can't just spread the Hasura claims onto the token like that after its already been generated. You have to include them as part of the actual token signing process so that they're already embedded in the access token

Comment: @JesseCarter
Thank you for the advice.But I couldn't get it. Do you mean I should edit "[...nextauth].tsx? Or other components?